# Does Editing a Comment with a Ping in it Re-Ping the Mentioned User?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

Specifics are not important for so general a question, but I was responding to a comment from another user under one of my answers and realized that I didn't know. This user seemed upset with my answer and so while I wanted to provide some context for my reasoning I certainly did not want to bother them with additional comment notifications.

**If you ping a user in a comment, post it, and then later edit that comment, does it ping the user a second time when the edited comment is submitted?**

Comment: We can probably easily science this, but it will require some real time prescence on the site, are you willing and able?

Comment: @Someone_Evil I'm on hand now, but since this is my question I'll get auto-pinged whether I'm tagged or not. I'd be fine with a placeholder answer which could, itself, be the stage for a test. Edit!

Comment: Fine, try to edit that comment while you still can, I'll see if I'm repinged

Comment: And I sure weren't pinged. I'll write up an answer so the question is closeable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It will not re-ping

From our experiment in the comments on this question, and from my own experience of using the site; editing comments will not refresh the notification from a mention. If a user is active enough to follow the notification within the 5 minute window for comment edits, they are presumably active enough to also catch any edits without the need for a new notification.

As a side note, the edit to the comment will not even show up unless the comments are reloaded, such as when posting your own comment, loading new ones, or refreshing the page.

Comment: Along with this, it might be worth mentioning whether editing the comment causes the preview version of the comment shown in the notification to be updated as well. (I think it does?)