# Does editing in @User into a comment still ping that user?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

Let's say I wanted to reply to someone's comment, but I forgot to add @user.

If I submit the comment, then realise, edit the comment, add @user, then confirm the edit, does the user receive a ping at that point, or is the ping only registered on originally submitting the comment?

---

Related (but my question is specifically adding the @user, not editing a comment already containing @user; i.e. my question is not a "re-ping", but a ping at all): [Does Editing a Comment with a Ping in it Re-Ping the Mentioned User?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9648/35259)

Comment: I think there is some special rules for 2 person conversations. Might need someone else to weigh in here.

Comment: This is a comment. It has now been edited to @linksassin

Comment: I did get a ping for that. I'll just double check this for science! By editing this to ping @LizWeir

Comment: Related on MSE: [Do users get notifications when @ was edited in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197393)

Comment: Relevant MSE question: [What events trigger an inbox notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/335251) The answer does address this scenario, as well as the scenario involved in the test above: "A post’s author comments on a post you have previously commented on, when the only other (undeleted) comments on the post belong to you or the author."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes, editing in a @mention pings the user

After a brief test in the comments of this question I can confirm that editing in an @mention does ping the user following the edit.